# how to delete extra space between buttons?

Tags: html, css, animation, button, web

please check out [this code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="buttons">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="buttons">About Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="buttons">Pictures</a>
        <a href="#" class="buttons">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main
{
    width: 64em;
    height: 25em;
}

#menu

    {
        background-color: #00b875;
        height: 3em;
    }

    .buttons
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        line-height: 3em;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-family: courier new;
        -moz-transition: 1s linear;
        -ms-transition: 1s linear;
        -o-transition: 1s linear;
        -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
        transition: 1s linear;
    }

    .buttons:hover
    {
        background-color: #0d96d6;
    }
```

when switching from one button to another very quickly, you'll notice that there is actually some gap in between two buttons. i want to get rid of this space. any ideas? if you do answer the question, please also explain why a certain property will fix this.

i know that it is tweakable using padding and margin, but the result is likely to get distorted upon zoom. please point out a stable way of solving the problem.

thanks

Comment: Any whitespace between tags in HTML is collapsed into a single space character, which is why you have that gap. You could float your elements left, put the `</a>` and `<a>` next to each other in the source or use a `font-size: 0` trick

Comment: ah this worked. thanks. i basically put <a> tags together.

Comment: @Bojangles Your comment is a better answer than the answers posted ;)

Comment: @xec Hah thanks. I've posted it as an answer now too

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/2/)

I've updated `display:inline-block;` to `display:block;` on the menu links and added `float:left` to them.

When you use `inline-block` you will have this ugly inline gap between elements caused by the whitespace between the elements in your `HTML` markup..

Comment: @amin and softsdev you are right however `display:block` makes more sense in my opinion..

Comment: hey, what if i want to move the buttons to the center of the page?

Comment: margin actually gives a margin for each button

Comment: so there are gaps again. i just want to move the location of the buttons across the horizontal plane

Comment: [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/8/) - works without gaps and buttons are centered. this is done with a centered wrapper `<div>` inside `#menu` - let me know if this worked for you

Comment: uh...where did .wrapper come from? it is not on html code? uh my bad found it. silly

Comment: thanks :) this is the best practice for achieving what you wanted in my opinion

Answer (score 15):

Any whitespace between tags in HTML is collapsed into a single space character, which is why you have that gap.

You could:

- Float your elements left,
- Put the `</a>` and `<a>` next to each other in the source or
- Use a `font-size: 0` trick

In this case, personally I'd float all my `<a>`s left although removing whitespace from your source comes with the fewest caveats, the only one being that it's more difficult to read.

Comment: hey, thank you for the answer. although your answer was correct, i was able to learn more form Yotam Omer. i hope you don't mind that i select his as the best answer. again, thank you.

Comment: Nah no worries, mine isn't very informative, just lists a few different ideas to get people started

Comment: font size 0 is genious!

Answer (score 9):

**Get rid of the spaces themselves:** this may look messy but actually it's the cleanest thing you can do. Anything you achieve with CSS tricks is just putting the spaces there and then denying their existence. Instead, you might want to omit them; the only problem to solve is readability.

So let's make it readable:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
        <!--
        --><a href="#" class="buttons">Home</a><!--
        --><a href="#" class="buttons">About Us</a><!--
        --><a href="#" class="buttons">Pictures</a><!--
        --><a href="#" class="buttons">Contact Us</a><!--
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, *I know it seems weird*, yes, but think about it. The real weirdo here is HTML itself, not giving you a clear way to do this. Consider it a special markup! It could as well be part of the HTML standard; technically, btw, it *is* 100% standard, you are free to use comments...

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution

http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/7/

```
.buttons
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: courier new;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's **2017**: wrap them inside an element with `display: inline-flex` and flex the inner buttons with something like `flex: 0 1 auto`:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex">
    <button style="flex: 0 1 auto">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/3/)*(JSFiddle)*

### CSS

```
#main {
    
    height: 25em;
}

#menu {
    background-color: #00b875;
    height: 3em;
}

.buttons {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-family: courier new;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear;
    -o-transition: 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear;
    transition: 1s linear;
}

.buttons:hover {
    background-color: #0d96d6;
}
```

Comment: You haven't fixed anything at all here; the space still remains

Answer (score 0):

I think with latest CSS possibilities a cleaner solution is to use `display:inline-flex` on menu and `display:flex` on buttons, and maybe `width:100%` on menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/NPqSr/212/

Answer (score 0):

Add the below style to your button. If required, make the margin negative for first of the few buttons.

button{
`margin: 0px;`
}

Answer (score 0):

If using bootstrap, can group buttons together by wrapping in div with class="btn-group".
Example for v3.3.7: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups-single

Visually might or might not be what you want. Has rounded corners on left and right ends and straight line between buttons.