# How to remove extra spaces surrounding a link in an accordion header?

Tags: html, css

I had to override the CSS property to preventing a broken line when there is a link in the text in an accordion header. But it creates another problem which is extra spaces around the link. How can I remove the extra spaces?
Here is my CSS code:

```
> .alert-header {
  color: black;
      a {
        display: inline!important;
        clear:left;

  }
```

Comment: either you've got some terribly broken css or you're using sass or something, specify which. what you've posted is not valid css at all.

Comment: You most likely have line breaks in your HTML between your links or list items. If so, it’s a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365017. Simply remove those line breaks.

Comment: Actually the "display: inline!important;" helps me to prevent the broken line causing by anchor tag. But it creates on more space around the hyperlink.