# Remove blank spaces between buttons in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I want to remove blank spaces between the buttons, so that when I for example hover over the NORMAL button, there will be no blank space between it and the HARD button. How can I do that and where do these blank spaces come from?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#stripe {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
}

button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: inherit;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    outline: none;
}

button:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

.selected {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
    <button class="mode">Easy</button>
    <button class="mode">Normal</button>
    <button class="mode selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This question was also asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365017/how-to-delete-extra-space-between-buttons/35148526

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Either remove the spaces and carriage returns, or put an HTML comment between them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#stripe {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    color: black;
}

button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: inherit;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    outline: none;
}

button:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

.selected {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripe">
    <button class="mode">Easy</button><!--
    --><button class="mode">Normal</button><!--
    --><button class="mode selected">Hard</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How does a carriage return result in these blank spaces?

Comment: @HuyTran it's a white space character, and the elements are `inline-block` so they're displayed inline. Just like you would see a `space between these words` in HTML or between `<span>` tags, or a space if there were carriage returns between the words/spans, you'll see the spaces/returns between elements set to `inline` and `inline-block`

Answer (score 42):

Browsers always add spaces between some elements, including buttons. To remove these, you need to set font-size to zero for their parent container. Then, to restore text size inside buttons, set font-size for them.

```
#stripe {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px; // Set font size that you need here
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Thumbs up.

However, as of this time, it does not render the same for me across browsers. I've also found this to be true of giving word-spacing a negative value. It terms of removing all space, it worked best on Chrome, decent on Edge, and not very good on Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

Add `display: flex;` to the parent container

Answer (score 1):

If using bootstrap, can group buttons together by wrapping in div with class="btn-group".
Example for v3.3.7: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups-single

Visually might or might not be what you want. Has rounded corners on left and right ends and straight line between buttons. Can probably restyle.